# A standard irrotational flow: is there an intuitive derivation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, potential-flow

It is said that a flow is irrotational if $\nabla \times \textbf{v}=0$ for the velocity profile. I know that there's a whole lot of vector calculus involved in "properly" writing the equations of fluid flow but it sometimes obfuscates intuitive understanding. Here is the situation that has been troubling me for long,

> Consider a radial velocity variation $\textbf{v}=v(r)\hat\theta$ (along tangential direction) which is irrotational. It is said that if we drop a stick in this profile, and it does not rotate, then we have $v(r)\propto \frac 1r$ because $\nabla\times v=0\implies \oint \vec v \cdot d\vec\ell=0$ by Stokes' theorem and now we can take two circles, one transversed clockwise, the other anticlockwise and join then by a kink that tends to zero size; thus, $v(R)\cdot 2\pi R=v(r)\cdot 2\pi r$.

This feels like dark magic! I have so much difficulty trying to get a geometric proof of the same as I always end up confusing myself. I think the subtlety lies in the "material derivative" v.s. "normal derivative at some point $(x,y,z)$ at time $t$".

I would be really grateful if someone could clarify and explain all this (and maybe make that "drop a stick" thing more formal; I think we're dealing with the material derivative here).

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778011/304394) might help. The YouTube video discussed there is one of the better ones.